# Xdebug Profiler creates a cachegrind.out file for auto-prepended file but not the target file

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

```
Looking to profile my web app, I have added the following settings to my Applications php.ini file:


zend_extension                  = "C:\hqp\xampp_1.7.4\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append          = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable          = 1 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir      = "c:\hqp\xampp_1.7.4\tmp\profiles"
xdebug.profiler_output_name     = "cachegrind.out.%s"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  = 1
```

In the httpd.conf file, a file is auto_prepended using the php value auto_prepend. The `cachegrind.out.*` file generated bears the name of this file (%s modifier in `xdebug.profiler_output_name`) and not the file that I actually looking to profile (for example the index.php file does not have a corresponding `cachegrind.out.filepath_index.php`)

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Seeing the same issue with version 2.2.1 and PHP 5.4.4 on a debian system

Comment: I moved onto XHProf btw...much better

Comment: so what? I have the same issue here...

Answer (score 2):

It might be that you are producing two files, and the second one overwrites the first.

You can change following parameters in your php.ini :

```
xdebug.profiler_append=1
```

This should append both calls in the same file.
source : https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

```
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%u.%p.%r
```

This should make sure that if there are 2 files, their names should be different.

https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#trace_output_name for other modifiers.